# ROS Industrial and Moveit installation

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there special instructions to install ROS-Industrial? Is there a step by step process to follow to first install ROS then Industrial and then Moveit?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206983/ros-industrial-and-moveit-installation/) by [cmackin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22119/cmackin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All open-source ROS-Industrial packages are released through the normal ROS buildfarm, so installation of those packages is identical to how you'd install other ROS packages (on Ubuntu, a simple `sudo apt-get ros-...`).

As to step-by-step guides, the ROS-Industrial [training exercises](http://ros-industrial.github.io/industrial_training) should provide you with that information, and more.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1